# Dynamically allocation memory for array of structs in c

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have two structures as shown below

```
struct server{
    // some members
};

struct msg{
    struct server* servers;
};
```

Then I do this.

```
struct msg msg1;
struct server s1,s2;

msg1.servers = (struct server *)malloc(2*sizeof(struct server));
msg1.servers[0] = &s1; // compilation error 
msg1.servers[1] = &s2;  // compilation error
```

This code does not compile and giving the following error : incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct server’ from type ‘struct server *’.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the expression `msg1.servers[0]` producets a `struct server` but you're providing a `struct server*` (a pointer type vs a non-pointer type).  There are two ways to fix this

The first is to simply provide the `struct server` instances by value as the code expects

```
msg1.servers[0] = s1;
msg1.servers[1] = s2;
```

This will work if `struct server` is a type that behaves properly when copied around.

The second is necessary if you want to continue using `struct server*` in the `struct msg`.  In this case you need a double pointer to store the server pointers.  And you need to adjust your `malloc` statement appropriately

```
struct msg{
    struct server** servers;
};

msg1.servers = malloc(2*sizeof(struct server*));
msg1.servers[0] = &s1; 
msg1.servers[1] = &s2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the ampersands:

```
msg1.servers[0] = s1;
msg1.servers[1] = s2;
```

Saying `&s1` would give you a *pointer* to a `struct server`, but `msg1.servers[0]` is a single element in the array you just allocated.

Answer (score 1):

`msg.servers` is a pointer to the type `server`. When you use `msg.servers[0]` you're dereferencing the pointer, so its type is now `server`, not `server *`, obviously you cannot assign the address of a `server` instance to it.

You probably want the following:

```
struct msg{
  struct server** servers;
};

struct msg msg1;
struct server s1,s2;

msg1.servers = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct server *));
msg1.servers[0] = &s1;
msg1.servers[1] = &s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
msg1.servers[0] = &s1;
```

An array subscript implicitly dereferences the pointer (`a[i] == *(a + i)`, so the type of the expression `msg1.servers[0]` is `struct server`, not `struct server *`.

Change your `struct msg` definition to

```
struct msg {
  struct server **servers; // servers will be an array of pointers
};
```

and the `malloc` call to

```
msg1.servers = malloc(2 * sizeof *msg1.servers);
```

and then the assignments will work.

**EDIT**

Or, like everyone else is pointing out, drop the `&` from the assignment.  It depends on what you intend `servers` to represent; is it an array of `struct server`, or an array of pointers to `struct server`?

Answer (score 0):

You need a array of pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct server{
        // some members
    };  

    struct msg{
        struct server ** servers;
    };  

    struct msg msg1;
    struct server s1,s2;

    if ((msg1.servers = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct server *))) == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
        return -1; 
    }   
    msg1.servers[0] = &s1; // compilation error 
    msg1.servers[1] = &s2;  // compilation error

    free(msg1.servers);

    return 0;
}
```